# Making a transistor circuit with sharp turn on (Small threshold interval)?

Tags: transistors, analog

I am measuring an analog voltage which should trigger an MCU by a GPIO when it falls below or goes above certain thresholds. At first I was planning on using comparators in order to get well defined thresholds, but I want to see if it's possible to make it work with only transistors somehow. If I connect BJTs as a Darlington pair I should get a sharper turn on, but is there any other way to get an even sharper turn on?

Comment: Differential amplifier using a long tailed pair.

Comment: You start with specs for threshold and tolerances then it’s easy to decide

Comment: If you don't need top speed, voltage references can make a good cheap solution ... check out TLV4031 etc, which are a variation of the '431 family but meant specifically for use as comparator

Comment: Buffered CMOS inverters with Vdd/2 approx threshold can be scaled with R ratios and have a voltage gain >1000. But you must define tolerances

Comment: How well defined a threshold?  How accurate?  How fast?  Do you just want to get a clean snap-action, with low precision and a lot of temperature dependence?  Or do you want to only switch states over a well-defined 1mV range that doesn't change with temperature?

Comment: Note that you're going to end up with at least two transistors and some resistors.  Given that with surface mount you can get a comparator in the same package as two transistors, and that two TO-92 transistors takes about the same space as one DIP-8, is this worth it?

Comment: A classic Schmitt trigger will do this.

Comment: The analog signal I'm measuring has a noise of around 250mV that I don't want to trigger the MCU. But if the signal reaches, say, 350mV then I'd like it to activate. So the window is quite small. A comparator would be the easiest but maybe there is another way?

Comment: The voltage I'm measuring can be biased at any voltage so it's not necessarily 350mV from GND, just from it's idle state where it varies up and down with 250mV. Even if it ends up with a lot of transistors and resistors it may be worthwhile I think. Can I keep stacking BJTs until the gain is super large?

Comment: Brian Drummond - Seems like I need to have to varying signals in order for a long tailed pair to be useful, is that correct?